# Footnote Labels

Tags: footnotes, revtex

I am new to using LaTeX/TeX (not sure what the difference is) and I am trying to add a footnote. The actual footnote appears alright with a number `[1]` in front of the text of the footnote itself. However, the `[?]` appears beside word adjacent to `\footnote{...}`. How might I make it show `[1]` instead of `[?]`?

Just in case there is something wrong with my packages, there are the ones I am using.

Thanks a lot!!

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname    #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
```

***Clarification***:

*In my code:*

"According to xxx fact sheet \footnote{See Appendix 1}"

*In the preview:*

The main text: "According to xxx fact sheet [?]"

The actual footnote: "[1] See Appendix 1"

Comment: Did you process your document *two* times?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: What do you mean by processing my document 2 times? (Sorry I am really inept!!)

Comment: "compile" it twice.

Comment: @Gonzalo two times for *footnotes*? I have doubts. I think a complete example is needed.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: thank you for explaining, but I am afraid I still don't know what compiling is... that bit of my code looks like "According to xxx fact sheet \footnote{See Appendix 1}" and the preview shows for the main text "According to xxx fact sheet [?]"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `revtex4` requires two times (I also didn't know until I tried it with `\documentclass{revtex4}\begin{document}\footnote{test}\end{document}`.

Comment: @Greg what I mean with processing (or compiling) is the process that you use to produce a pdf document from your code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks for commenting! what does "twice" mean? Would you mind explaining what I have to do more explicitly? Sorry for my ineptness and thanks in advance!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Oh! Thanks!! It is working now!!!